# Can we automatically save plots from Plot widgets each time inputs are refreshed?

Tags: orange

I see that:

- It is possible to generate a csv output using the "Save Data" widget each time the inputs are reloaded.
- That the plot of a eg Scatter Plot widget can be either saved to file (using the floppy disk button in the Scatter Plot widget window) or added to a report.
- The report does not refresh itself when the inputs are reloaded.

My question: Is there a way to automatically generate png of a Scatter Plot (and any other Plot widget present in the flow) each time the input data is reloaded?
In practice, it would be the same effect as clicking the floppy disk button on every Plot widget.

Alternatively, a report that refreshes itself and saves automatically each time the inputs are reloaded could be a working solution for me.

PS: The Save Image widget seems to not be meant for that purpose… Or am I using it wrong?